# Amortized analysis of Depth first search

Tags: algorithms

I have seen an exercise saying that "show that running time of DFS in an undirected graph is Θ(E+V) by using amortized analysis". Here is what i think, each call to DFS algorith takes O(1+E<sub>v</sub>) where E<sub>v</sub> is the number of nodes adjacent to v. Then the total time is found if we sum O(1+E<sub>v</sub>) for all vertexes, and it is Θ(E+V). Is this an amortized analysis? Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: That looks good. What you need to emphasize is the $\sum_vE_v=2E=O(E)$.

Comment: When a problem is too easy, it is often hard to tell what would satisfy the grader's requirement for "amortized analysis". Another way to say it is that you "pay" 2 time unit coins for each edge before the algorithm starts (that costs $O(E)$ amoritzed). Then, whenever you access an edge you use a time unit coin. Since any edge is accessed exactly twice, you don't need to pay for the edges at all during the DFS itself. So you pay $O(E)$ in advance and $O(V)$ during the DFS. That's more "amortizedish", but really, you got the point.